# Specify Ruby method namespace for readability

Tags: ruby

This is a bit of a weird question, but I'm not quite sure how to look it up. In our project, we already have an existing concept of a "shift". There's a section of code that reads:

```
foo.shift
```

In this scenario, it's easy to read this as trying to access the `shift` variable of object `foo`. But it could also be `Array#shift`. Is there a way to specify which class we expect the method to belong to? I've tried variations such as:

```
foo.send(Array.shift)
Array.shift(foo)
```

to make it more obvious which method was being called, but I can't get it to work. Is there a way to be more explicit about which class the method you're trying to call belongs to to help in code readability?

Comment: What do you mean, "could also be Array#shift"? Only if `foo` is an actual array.

Comment: It is an array -- the method call succeeds. Just trying to help with readability so it's more obvious. There is no other `shift` method resolvable in this particular part of the code. It's just that it's confusing to read given our internal vocabulary, so it would be nice to be more explicit about which method is actually being called.

Comment: If you want to improve code readability, then... Don't give variables the same names as methods?

Comment: Rename your `foo` then, so that it's obvious that it is a collection/array. `elements.shift` doesn't really leave much room for guessing.

Comment: If you want to be *really painfully explicit*, then you could write: `foo.shift()` and `foo.instance_variable_get("@shift")`. But why not just use a different variable name, and avoid confusion in the first place?

Comment: It's in a Rails context -- the name `foo` isn't a problem. It's that we often have associations called `shift`. The idea of renaming `foo` to `foo_array` could work. Also something like `foo.to_a.shift` could work? I assumed there would be a straightforward way to do this, but it sounds like there's not! Could you somehow bind Array.shift to a specific instance?

Comment: The principle behind Ruby code design is you *should not care* if it's an Array `shift`, a list shift, a squirrel shift, or a hot-dog shift. It's a shift and so long as that shifting meets your expectations then it's a valid operation. The only way `shift` maps to something unexpected is if the implementation isn't documented properly and/or isn't intuitive and obvious.

Comment: I'm guessing, this is only a (theoretical) problem when that expression is in a relative isolation, like one-liner methods `def bar; foo.shift; end`? I imagine it'd be trivial to tell which is it, if this line had more context around it.

Comment: I think what I'm looking for is: `Array.instance_method(:shift).bind(foo).call`. Very verbose, but probably about as close as I can get in terms of specificity. If somebody wants to answer with that I'd be happy to mark it as the answer. I guess I'm trying to bring stronger typing to a language that doesn't have it, so the whole endeavour is probably a bad idea to start with. Thanks for your input all!

Comment: @aardvarkk: you can post a self-answer (even accept it, I think)

Comment: @aardvarkk  "I guess I'm trying to bring stronger typing to a language that doesn't have it, so the whole endeavour is probably a bad idea to start with" - that is a very accurate description of this :)

Answer (score 3):

On a fundamental level you shouldn't be concerned about this sort of thing and you *absolutely can't* tell the Array `shift` method to operate on anything but an Array object. Many of the core Ruby classes are implemented in C and have optimizations that often depend on specific internals being present. There's safety measures in place to prevent you from trying to do something too crazy, like rebinding and applying methods of that sort arbitrarily.

Here's an example of two "shifty" objects to help illustrate a real-world situation and how that applies:

```
class CharacterArray < Array
  def initialize(*args)
    super(args.flat_map(&:chars))
  end

  def inspect
    join('').inspect
  end
end

class CharacterList < String
  def shift
    slice!(0, 1)
  end
end
```

You can smash `Array#shift` on to the first and it will work *by pure chance* because you're dealing with an Array. It won't work with the second one because that's not an Array, it's missing significant methods that the `shift` method likely depends on.

In practice it doesn't matter what you're using, they're both the same:

```
list_a = CharacterArray.new("test")

list_a.shift
# => "t"
list_a.shift
# => "e"
list_a << "y"
# => "sty"

list_b = CharacterList.new("test")

list_b.shift
# => "t"
list_b.shift
# => "e"
list_b << "y"
# => "sty"
```

These both implement the same interfaces, they both produce the same results, and as far as you're concerned, as the caller, that's good enough. This is the foundation of [Duck Typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) which is the philosophy Ruby has deeply embraced.

If you try the rebind trick on the `CharacterList` you're going to end up in trouble, it won't work, yet that class delivers on all your expectations as far as interface goes.

**Edit**: As Sergio points out, you can't use the rebind technique, Ruby abruptly explodes:

```
Array.instance_method(:shift).bind(list_b).call
# => Error: bind argument must be an instance of Array (TypeError)
```

If readability is the goal then that has 35 more characters than `list_b.shift` which is usually going dramatically in the wrong direction.

Comment: "you absolutely should not tell the Array shift method to operate on anything but an Array object" - should not, yes. And actually one __can't__ do that.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev It's a good observation, so I'm adding that to the answer.

Comment: I'm with you here and I think that proper naming should be the answer, but, as far as I understand, he wants to make it dead obvious that `foo` is an array. And that line kinda does the job (especially coupled with the knowledge that it'll expode if foo is not an array)

Comment: Also, as far as I understand, the situation with the different shifts there is not at all like two implementation of character collection here. More like `team.shift`. Where what `shift` does varies based on what exactly `team` is there, `Array<Employee>` (removes employee from the team) or `Team` (returns hours for the work shift). ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @SergioTulentsev The only way to make it "dead obvious" that it's an array is `foo = Array.new` in which case there's zero ambiguity. This sort of mad-scientist binding is a sign that you don't trust your variable, in which case you can't trust your code, in which case the whole thing is suspect and you're deep in tin-foil hat territory. The most paranoid you should be is `foo.is_a?(Array)` but even that is problematic as there are array-like structures that aren't strictly inheriting from that.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev If `shift` means "work shift", and doesn't actually shift things, and it's passed into a method that expects otherwise then that's a bug in your code and no amount of defensive programming can fix that. Instead you need better tests so that error is detected before you push your code live. People used to the strict type checking that a compiler typically provides often figure if it compiles it's good, so there's no reason to test, but they couldn't be more wrong. Ruby has no initial safety net, so you're always responsible for building tests to verify assumptions.

Comment: I know, I know :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev is correct in his assessment: our code is *not* concerned that `shift` is being called on anything except an array. It's only to aid other developers in *reading* the code, because the concept of "shift" (like a work shift) exists in various places throughout our code. It's just an unfortunate naming collision that I was hoping could be resolved by being a bit more verbose about the function call, ideally making it more explicit and less likely to confuse the reader about its meaning.

Comment: @aardvarkk That's a matter of documentation and, as is always the case with anything programming, solving the hard problem of *naming things*. If you call it `work_shift` instead of shift, then it's more clear. You can also call the array variable `x_array` instead of `x` if that communicates better. It's impossible to avoid naming collisions entirely, it's a fact of life, the best you can do is minimize them.

Comment: @tadman Agreed -- a quick line comment alongside the function call would also help. I mentioned the solution of naming the variable with `_array` appended in my answer.

Comment: It seems like you're finding how Ruby deals with this kind of awkward, that there's no assurance you're calling the right method, but that's just how Ruby works and there's a number of cultural conventions that have emerged to deal with that. If you embrace the ambiguity you can do a lot of amazing things in a way that's still easily understood by anyone familiar with how Ruby can work. If you try and Java-ify Ruby you'll end up fighting a war you can't win and making rigid code that's hard to maintain and iterate on. The "When in Rome" Principle applies: do as Ruby does when writing Ruby.

Answer (score 1):

After some discussion in the comments, one solution is:

```
Array.instance_method(:shift).bind(foo).call
```

Super ugly, but gets across the idea that I wanted which was to completely specify which instance method was actually being called. Alternatives would be to rename the variable to something like `foo_array` or to call it as `foo.to_a.shift`.

The reason this is difficult is that Ruby is not strongly-typed, and this question is all about trying to bring stronger typing to it. That's why the solution is gross! Thanks to everybody for their input!

Comment: That's not really a solution, it's a giant hack and it is not general purpose.

Comment: `foo.to_a.shift` may operate on a copy, so that's also a problem. It doesn't properly alter the original which most people would reasonably expect `shift` to do.